# A Lemma in the book " Mathematical Method for financial markets" (Chapter 5, Section 5.7)

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, levy-processes

In page 307, Section 5.7, Chapter 5 of the book "mathematical methods for financial markets" by Jeanblanc, Yor and Chesney, Lemma 5.7.1 is given as follows:

Lemma 5.7.1.1 Let $W$ be a Brownian motion, $L$ its local time at level $0$ and $\tau_{l}=\inf\{ t:L_{t}\geq l\}$. Then

$$(W_{u}, u\leq\tau_{l}|\tau_{l}=t)\overset{law}{=}(W_{u}, u\leq t|L_{t}=l, W_{t}=0)\quad(1)$$
As  a consequence, 
   $$(W_{\tau_{l}-u}, u\leq\tau_{l})\overset{law}{=}(W_{u}, u\leq \tau_{l})$$
Its proof begins as assuming (1), then---.

My question is how to prove (1). There is no proof in their proof. Is it trivial? I am confused the condition $W_{t}=0$ in the right side of (1). Any references are very appreciated.